# Running a program located in Mac machine from a windows machine

Tags: windows, macos, remoting

I have a situation like, I need to run a program inmy Mac machine from a windows machine. Both are in same network.
If I have written the program as jar executable and located it in Mac ,
Will it be able to execute remotely from a windows machine.

I know this can be achieved by hosting a web service in Mac and accessing this service from windows can be done.

I need to know is there any other way so that I can execute a shell command in windows and trigger this program in Mac

The program will be a command line app. I need to programmatically invoke this app from windows PC

Comment: Is the program a GUI app or a command-line tool?

Comment: You can remotely execute command on the mac with ssh.

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: @Nikhil I think those confirm Bill's answer.

Comment: I think you need PLINK.EXE on your Windows box... https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mac, you need to enable Remote Login in the Sharing pane of System Preferences. On the Windows machine, you need an SSH client. You can then use the SSH client to connect to the Mac (with the proper credentials) and issue commands.